# Right way to watch mutable data structures in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-structures, watch

Let's say that I have an object *arr* in my service that contains various key,value pairs. I modify *arr* from time to time by iterating over it and modifying its key,value pairs by removing some, adding new ones, or modifying existing ones.

Now, it is my understanding that if I place a watch on *arr* in my controller so that I know when this object is modified, every time *arr* is modified the watch will be triggered, so that if I have a for loop of length *n* in my service modifying *arr* *n* times, my watch function will be triggered *n* times.

So, if I only want to trigger the watch function when the for loop is finished, and not have it be called *n* times, what is the best way of doing this? My immediate thought is to set a flag in the service *isDone*, set it to false at the start of the loop and true at the end, and only trigger a watch when going from false -> to true. But, this seems very clunky and old-fashioned, so I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I would probably clone the array, make all the changes to the clone, then replace the original with the clone at the end of the operations.

Comment: Another option would be make a flags for if the list is currently being changed (may not be needed for your purpose) and has been changed. Something like: Initially -->`changed = false; changing = false`, once the loop starts --> `changed =false; changing = true`, and once it finishes --> `changed = true; changing = false`, then reset the flags when the function has been triggered. This way you just watch the changed flag. For better use, you could have the changing variable store what changes are being made, then transfer them to the changed variable.

Comment: @Claies This would be ideal but the problem is that this breaks bindings and watches. When you replace the object, the bindings and watches are still watching the old reference of the object and do not notice the change.

Comment: @Claies Actually after trying some more things turns out my earlier comment is not true. Trying to wrap my head around this...